# Extract a rar file with a password that contains special characters

Tags: password, compression, rar, decompression

How can I extract a rar file with a password that contains special characters like `'`, `"`, `` ` ``, `/`, `\`, `^`,   *(space)*, `!`, `?`, `{`, `}`, `[`, `]`, `$`, `&`, `%`, `*`, `~`, `:`, `,`, `<`, `>`, etc.

Here is an example of *PASSWORD* :

```
iuPx?tqCN'b.?LZ$=EL59L3?L/fPYii)caC'u8gYGPRy2mKCqwhzAa'RmKH} &Sf.4V>Q@z+K[XXux6$;iCixxcY/J$c,G6Xb#\SAf',KrM Z{CZ&_z^_5)W3xgGV{wU[v~sWf!]ciLLXvKm^>DC<}~]uypo}oAE{*hbYied',u5YKHS( RNoNiRvCHR{{QniDE[_AWw2{79s%SrdQE& &74(T^LjBk#\Q9ZT@48'-bE(q;pwYXw<g"dHv&DfBf2nrj;;UwrB};J,U%yg64P<$w@8[HXxhY~_o-2y;wv)in;
```

I have already tried with these commands:

```
unrar x -pPASSWORD FILE.rar
unrar x -p"PASSWORD" FILE.rar
7z x FILE.rar -pPASSWORD
7z x FILE.rar -p"PASSWORD"
```

but there's nothing to do.

I also tried it with [File Roller](http://fileroller.sourceforge.net/) and it give me this error:

> An error occurred while loading the archive.

Also [PeaZip](http://www.peazip.org/peazip-linux.html) give me an error:

> ' quote character cannot be used by PeaZip GUI in passwords under current system

How can I extract this rar file?

Comment: So you have an encrypted RAR archive that has a very long password containing special characters, but you *know* the real password, right? It's not that you want to crack or brute-force the archive?

Comment: @ByteCommander Yes, I know the password!

Comment: on what system was the file generated? Different operating systems  (and I mean Windows/Linux/Mac) will have different rules for this. It is probably best to use a similar operating system and the same archive program to restore the file.

Comment: If you don't use the `-p` option with 7z, it will prompt for the password. What happens if you enter the password then?

Comment: @muru It gives me a `Segmentation fault`.

Comment: @muru But it works with `unrar x FILE.rar`!

Comment: Time to file bug reports, then.

Answer (score 2):

What matters is how you pass your password to the unrar program in terminal. For special characters you should use `\` (the escape character) before them.

For example, if your password is `a" \?`

what you should type is `a\"\ \\\?`

See [this Wikipedia article on escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)